# How to add global site tag in nuxt js and how to send event?

Tags: google-analytics, nuxt.js

**I send Like this. How to configure global site tag in nuxt js**.

```
methods: {
    track(){
        this.$gtag('event', 'aaa', {
            'event_category' : 'bbb',
            'event_label' : 'ccc'
        });
    }
},
```

Global site tag link
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs

Answer (score 7):

Inside your plugins folder, add the following `google-analytics.client.js`:

**swap ###TAG ID### for your tag.**

```
export default () => {
  const script = document.createElement('script')
  script.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=###TAG ID###'
  script.async = true
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', '###TAG ID###');
  gtag('event', 'aaa');
  gtag('event_category', 'bbb');
  gtag('event_label', 'ccc');
});
```

Then add it to your `nuxt.config.js`. Add the following to your plugins:

```
plugins: [
  { src: '~/plugins/google-analytics.client.js'},
],
```

Comment: Thanks, best option for those using Nuxtjs 2+